# Where is the generic Other Image?

Tags: macos, login-screen

On a mac, when you enable 'Other' on the login screen so that network accounts can log in, the large circular image that comes along with it is a gray silhouette of three heads.  Where is this image on the hard drive?  I'd like to swap it out with something else.

Comment: What version(s) of macOS are you running?

Comment: I poked around in various suspect apps in `Macintosh HD > System > Library > CoreServices` but found nothing. The file may be stored in `Macintosh HD > System > Library > User Template` somewhere, but you need enable and be logged in as `root` to get into that directory. That's the directory where default account templates are stored. Perhaps **Other** is in there somewhere. (macOS 10.14.3)

Comment: Anything in /System is likely to be protected by SIP, and so not easily altered.

Comment: @benwiggy Disabling SIP is easy enough...

Comment: By default, on every mac I manage, I enable the root user (and almost always login as root) as well as disable SIP.  If the OS gets screwed up it is quick and easy to do a fresh reinstall of the os.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is here:

```
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LoginUIKit.framework/Versions/Current/Frameworks/LoginUICore.framework/Resources/OtherUser.png
```